# why function name in string is interpreted in php?

Tags: php

Hello I'm writing an article allowing to bypass a filter that allows only base_convert except that there is something I discovered recently is that when we write this syntax in php:

```php
"system"("id")
```

the function is interpreted, do you have a technical explanation for this?

Thanks to you !

Comment: Probably comes from the variable function syntax: `$f()`, where `$f` refers to a function *by name* (because that’s the only way to refer to functions, since they’re not first class objects). Though I’ve never seen the syntax used like this.

Comment: In general, a function name as a string can be used wherever a function is required. For example, you can pass a function name to `array_map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in PHP aren't first-class objects. What does that mean? When you want to pass around *a function*, for example as callback to [`array_map`](https://php.net/array_map), you cannot just pass *the function* itself like so:

```
function my_callback() { ... }

array_map(my_callback, $some_array)
```

`my_callback` here is interpreted as a constant, and barring its existence, a bare string. (This works in other languages where functions *are* first class objects.) You can only [pass the function *by name*](https://www.php.net/callable), which means you pass a string that contains the name of the function:

```
array_map('my_callback', $some_array)
```

PHP will then look up the globally registered function with the name "my_callback" and use it.

This means inside `array_map` it must look something like this:

```
function array_map($callback, $array) {
    $callback($array);  // let's ignore the "mapping" part…
}
```

So, a variable can hold the name of a function, and "calling" that variable which holds the name of a function actually calls that function.

Now, we know that a variable can just as well be replaced with a literal of the same value:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = $a + $b;
```

is the same as:

```
$c = 1 + 2;
```

The same happens to hold for calling-strings-with-names-of-functions:

```
'my_callback'($array)
```

Note that this only works since PHP 7, where the PHP parser got a huge revamping. Before, `$f()` was sort of a special case hack, but the PHP 7+ parser properly follows the variable-is-substitutable-by-literal logic.